# How do I apply machine learning classification methods to 1D time series data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have IMU data (accelerometer, magnetometer, and gyroscope) during a variety of exercises (squats, push-ups, sit-ups, burpees). These exercises are completed in a single 1D time series signal and I would like to use a machine learning classification method to identify the different exercises within the signal. I do not want to condense the signal into 0D peaks and build my features that way but rather keep the time domain intact. Below is a figure showing example data from the accelerometer that contains the four exercises. My question therefore is which method would be most effective at doing so? K-means clustering would be perfect in the 0D sense so is there a 1D equivalent? Any resources to python (sklearn) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I do not think I understand your need or reason in requiring ML in your use case. Could you talk more about that since it would be helpful to know what you are trying to classify?

Comment: Also, could you explain your x and y axis?

Comment: I'm basically trying to conduct Human Activity Recognition. Build a classifier so that when someone conducts a workout, I can identify which exercise they are doing, allowing me to rate their performance and provide feedback. X is time, Y is raw Accelerometer output (g's) of the x axis. I have X, Y, and Z, for accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that rather than classification, you want to do clustering. Classification is putting data into predefined categories (usually based on some training data), whereas clustering is used to group parts of data into previously unknown classes. Here is a short table showing the difference between classification and clustering.
[image: classification vs clustering]

One thing you can do is chop the time series up into overlapping samples (perhaps 1000 timesteps each) and calculate some statistics for those (mean, variance, etc.). Then perform K-Means Clustering on the statistics you calculated.

After performing clustering, you could use the classes identified during clustering to create training data for a classifier.

Comment: He makes no reference to audio. Nor does he define what the axis of the graph is apart from it being accelerometer data from the 4 exercises. That being said, kmeans is a good clustering algorithm but not a very good classifier. So your answer is more of a comment rather than an actual answer

Comment: Sorry, I normally do this for audio so I wrote audio out of habit. It applies to any time series data though. The data seems to be raw accelerometer output (how fast the accelerometer is moving at any one time). Also, he isn't actually looking for classification (he doesn't have pre-defined classes), he wants clustering on the data to identify the classes for him.

Comment: No worries! I agree with you about using clustering to identify classes for him. But he wanted to ***use a machine learning classification method to identify the different exercises within the signal***. If you re-edit your answer to state it's better to use k-means to help cluster data to identify classes which would in turn help create a training dataset for classification based algorithms I will upvote your answer :)

Comment: Right, added an explanation on classification vs clustering and how he can use clustering for identifying classes for aiding with classification later.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Ok great. Thank you Omegastick & @HarisNadeem . To clarify, yes, it is raw accelerometer output (g's) in 1 DoF over time. The signal pattern clearly indicates four different exercises. I'm still unsure about how to cut and overlay the data like you suggested. Each tool has X,Y,Z and I have two IMUs per person. This totals 18 time-series per person. Is there any possible way to concatenate all time-series when running the clustering analysis? Would I still have to chop each signal up into  samples (e.g. 20) so really I would have 20*18 time-series per person?

Comment: Well, it depends on how are you receiving the data? Are you getting the information from each exercise independently or are they getting meshed together in one data stream? If they are one meshed data stream, is it possible to obtain data of each exercise independently from one another?

Answer (score 0):

For time-series data the standard method is bag-of-frames, chopping it up into small  chunks called frames. The frames can be overlapped and windowed or disjoint. Frame size is an important hyper-parameter and depends on task. Features like min,max,median,variance,RMS are calculated on each frame. To use variation over time in the classifier one uses lagged or delta features. Lagged features are values from the frames before. Delta features are computed as the difference of current frame to the previous one.

For classification you will need to label the segments of different activities. Note that for human-activity detection on accelerator data there are also tons of public datasets available, like [UCI: Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones)

Comment: Hi @jonnor. Yes, I ended up binning the signal into smaller epochs and using a variety of descriptive parameters as features for each window. I hadn't thought about including info from the previous window, which is a very neat idea when and could really help when the person is doing a block of exercises.

I've also begun looking into Hidden Markov Models as that seems to be the way human activity recognition is done with a continuous signal without having to bin it.